# Woocommerce - Paypal checkout shows my email, not business

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am using Woocommerce (unable to fund support unless I bought a product made directly by them.

The issue is, I was about to test out my site and noticed that the checkout page shows my personal Email address instead of my Business name, which to a customer would look VERY strange.

This picture shows what I mean, I didn't want my email shown. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KSVs.jpg

I have disable the sandbox box option too but still it shows my email

Comment: This isn't a WooCommerce question. I'm 99% sure that your PayPal name/checkout experience is customized via your PayPal settings.

Comment: You can change the heading to your business name if you have a Business PayPal account. In your PayPal account, click on 'Profile' under 'My Account', click my Business Info, click update next to Business Information, click change name next to your name, select Business Name Change (business name), click continue, change the name and click continue and the name will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your PayPal account and go through all of the options in your profile.  Make sure you have everything under Website Payment Preferences, Payment Receiving Preferences, etc. configured how you want.  That should take care of what shows up during checkout on your site.

That said, you may want to take a look at [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/).  It's free and allows you to setup Express Checkout, which is a more advanced version of PayPal checkout.  It comes with options in the plugin to customize the checkout pages with your company logo, and it also allows you to enable "guest checkout" so that the option to pay with a credit card (without a PayPal account) is more prominent on the PayPal checkout pages.